# Компиляция kivy приложения в .apk

Tags: android, kivy

При написании приложения я использовал такие библиотеки, как cv2, PyTorch и по мелочи. После компиляции приложение весило 1.8гб. Как я понял во время компиляции загружались все используемые библиотеки полностью. Как это исправить? Это ненормально, что 30 строк кода весят почти 2гб

Comment: 0_0 по-моему, все эти библиотеки вместе взятые три раза не наберут и трехсот мигов. А во-вторых, даже если, используйте не полный импорт "import kivy", а "from kivy import function". По-моему, это здорово облегчает.

Comment: Один только pyTorch весит 800мб. А не полный импорт тоже не помогает. Всё равно библиотека целиком подгружается

Comment: Тогда никак, скорее всего.